# Security bypass: How to run application in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, software-security

I need to run "Yanosik" in Android Emulator Genymotion. 
Developers block in app runnning it in Android Emulator - when I try download it via Playstore, it says that my device is incompatible. When I try install it from .apk file, its still crash. Its any method to spoof emulator as real phone and run this program? If RE group is not right for this question, please tell me where I should ask.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the app is crashing because you're running it inside of an emulator, *Maybe your device is really **incompatible***.

After you made sure your device is compatible with the app your next step would be to try and trace where the function checks if it's an emulator or not. You could try and use stack traces printed to log or decompile the app and check for known APIs.

Patch the function and you should be able to use the app on your emulator.
But if I had to guess, I'd say your device is incompatible.